# How to Configure an OAuth connection setting in web App Bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I am a new Bot developer. I went through the [Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to implement authentication in Bot. It is a very good document and easily understandable. Even though, I stuck within "Configure an OAuth connection setting" step. It is mentioned like **OAuth Connection Settings** can be seen under **Settings** of Bot Service resource. Unfortunately, I couldn't see those settings. Could anybody advise me, what did I wrong here?

Please see the **Settings** in below image. There is no **Service Provider Connection Settings**. It should come below **Analytics** section

[image: Service Provider Connection Settings missing]

Are there any other ways to add authentication in Chat Bot?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do anything wrong. OAuth Connection Settings have been temporarily (14 Jun to 17 Jun) disabled to fix a bug in Azure. They're expected to be back up by mid morning (Pacific Standard Time) on 17 Jun 2019.

Comment: Oh.. Is that so?  I was banging my head to get this configuration man. Could you give me the link from Azure which describes this bug?

Comment: Wasn't a link. I work on the bot framework support team.

Comment: It hasn't fixed yet. Has it?

Comment: I think it hasn't enabled yet. Could you suggest me an idea to set the ConnectionName programmatically from appsettings.json?

Comment: email me at v-jewail@microsoft.com

Comment: I hope, you got my mail. Could you advise..?